# Converter array multi em json Array Multi

Tags: php, javascript, json

Através de um print_r, estou imprimindo o array (***objeto***`)`$todos`, e estou obtendo o seguinte array **multidimensional**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Produtos Object
        (
            [idProduto:Produtos:private] => 1
            [tipo:Produtos:private] => mp
            [modelo:Produtos:private] => F540 2 BAN.PNEU. 100 X 60
            [bandejas:Produtos:private] => 2
            [peso:Produtos:private] => 0
            [prensagem:Produtos:private] => 0
            [precoUnitario:Produtos:private] => 6500
            [comprimento:Produtos:private] => 100
            [largura:Produtos:private] => 60
            [cabo:Produtos:private] => 0
            [ligacao:Produtos:private] => n
            [potencia:Produtos:private] => 0
            [consumo:Produtos:private] => 0
            [corrente:Produtos:private] => 0
            [disjuntor:Produtos:private] => 0
            [descricao:Produtos:private] => 
Valor promocional limitado frete grátis ,para SP ,RJ ,MG ,ES. Os demais será cobrado apenas de SP para sua cidade ,valor de 500,00 ,a ser pago na entrega .



MAQUINA TOTALMENTE INDUSTRIAL E 100% NACIONAL .PRODUÇÃO DE ATÉ MIL PÇS POR DIA EM HORÁRIO NORMAL DE TRABALHO ,SISTEMA DIGITAL AUTOMATIZADO DE ÚLTIMA GERAÇÃO , SISTEMA PNEUMÁTICO COMPACTO E UNIFORME RECEBENDO A MESMA PRESSÃO EM TODA ÁREA DE ESTAMPAGEM, EVITANDO ASSIM OS SOMBREAMENTOS E EFEITOS FANTASMA NA ESTAMPA , SISTEMA DE RESISTÊNCIA DE ALTA QUALIDADE A MELHOR DO MERCADO AÇO INOX 304 , DANDO UMA VIDA ÚTIL MUITO SUPERIOR AS DEMAIS DO MERCADO , E FÁCIL TROCAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS NÃO SENDO NECESSÁRIO TÉCNICO NO LOCAL , COM APENAS 4 PARAFUSOS O CLIENTE MESMO FAZ A TROCA, AS DEMAIS A RESISTÊNCIA É FUNDIDA NA CHAPA DE ALUMÍNIO SENDO IMPOSSÍVEL A TROCA APENAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS , TEMOS TODAS AS PÇS DA PRENSA EM VALORES BEM ACESSÍVEIS. 
            [estoque:Produtos:private] => 7
            [freteGratis:Produtos:private] => s
            [bloqueado:Produtos:private] => n
        )

    [1] => Produtos Object
        (
            [idProduto:Produtos:private] => 2
            [tipo:Produtos:private] => mp
            [modelo:Produtos:private] => F540 2 BAN.PNEU.80X100 A VISTA BOLETO PAGSEGURO
            [bandejas:Produtos:private] => 2
            [peso:Produtos:private] => 190
            [prensagem:Produtos:private] => 300
            [precoUnitario:Produtos:private] => 7500
            [comprimento:Produtos:private] => 70
            [largura:Produtos:private] => 100
            [cabo:Produtos:private] => 6
            [ligacao:Produtos:private] => b
            [potencia:Produtos:private] => 7500
            [consumo:Produtos:private] => 3
            [corrente:Produtos:private] => 35
            [disjuntor:Produtos:private] => 40
            [descricao:Produtos:private] => MAQUINA TOTALMENTE INDUSTRIAL E 100% NACIONAL .PRODUÇÃO DE ATÉ MIL PÇS POR DIA EM HORÁRIO NORMAL DE TRABALHO ,SISTEMA DIGITAL AUTOMATIZADO DE ÚLTIMA GERAÇÃO , SISTEMA PNEUMÁTICO COMPACTO E UNIFORME RECEBENDO A MESMA PRESSÃO EM TODA ÁREA DE ESTAMPAGEM, EVITANDO ASSIM OS SOMBREAMENTOS E EFEITOS FANTASMA NA ESTAMPA , SISTEMA DE RESISTÊNCIA DE ALTA QUALIDADE A MELHOR DO MERCADO AÇO INOX 304 , DANDO UMA VIDA ÚTIL MUITO SUPERIOR AS DEMAIS DO MERCADO , E FÁCIL TROCAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS NÃO SENDO NECESSÁRIO TÉCNICO NO LOCAL , COM APENAS 4 PARAFUSOS O CLIENTE MESMO FAZ A TROCA, AS DEMAIS A RESISTÊNCIA É FUNDIDA NA CHAPA DE ALUMÍNIO SENDO IMPOSSÍVEL A TROCA APENAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS , TEMOS TODAS AS PÇS DA PRENSA EM VALORES BEM ACESSÍVEIS. 
www.topuhrens.de




            [estoque:Produtos:private] => 8
            [freteGratis:Produtos:private] => n
            [bloqueado:Produtos:private] => n
        )
```

é óbvio que esse array é bem mais extenso. Porém, 2 resultados são o suficiente para eu tirar minha dúvida.

Preciso fazer

```
echo json_encode($todos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Na esperança de converter o resultado em `JSON`
Mas estou obtendo:

```
{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"6":{},"7":{},"8":{},"9":{},"10":{},"11":{},"12":{},"13":{},"14":{},"15":{},"16":{},"17":{},"18":{},"19":{},"20":{},"21":{},"22":{},"23":{},"24":{},"25":{},"26":{},"27":{},"28":{},"29":{},"30":{},"31":{},"32":{},"33":{},"34":{},"35":{},"36":{},"37":{},"38":{},"39":{},"40":{},"41":{},"42":{},"43":{},"44":{},"45":{},"46":{},"47":{},"48":{},"49":{},"50":{},"51":{},"52":{},"53":{},"54":{},"55":{},"56":{},"57":{},"58":{},"59":{},"60":{},"61":{},"62":{},"63":{},"64":{},"65":{},"66":{},"67":{},"68":{},"69":{},"70":{},"71":{},"72":{},"73":{},"74":{},"75":{},"76":{},"77":{},"78":{},"79":{},"80":{},"81":{},"82":{},"83":{},"84":{},"85":{},"86":{},"87":{},"88":{},"89":{},"90":{},"91":{},"92":{},"93":{}}
```

Como resultado do `jSon`.

Parece que os `arrays` internos não estão sendo populados na conversão.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Seu problema é que os atributos dos seus objetos estão privados. Você pode deixar publicos (não recomendo) ou criar uma função dentro de cada um que retorne os dados e chama-la.

Comment: Tenta adicionar essa função na sua classe  `public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }`, acho que pode funcionar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613792/how-do-i-json-encode-private-properties-in-php

Comment: mas mesmo sendo privados, o que chega para o json_encode é o retorno de um método, não um acesso direto aos atributos da classe.

Comment: dá null como resposta; Estou fazendo assim: echo json_encode(get_object_vars($todos));

Comment: Acredito que a função deve estar dentro da própria classe, talvez de fora não consiga. Fiz uma gambetosa aqui: `public function toArray()
    {
        return (array) $this;
    }` dessa forma dá pra chamar assim `json_encode($obj->toArray())`

Comment: então, dessa forma deu certo: echo json_encode(serialize($todos));. Mas existe um campo de texto que traz html nele. Como em um deles existe u link, o resto abaixo todo está como link. Como resolver?

Comment: Acredito que seja apenas visual. Se você quer ver o resultado como vem do php sem renderizar o html basta colocar seu resultado entre `<pre>`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86386/discussion-between-edson-alves-and-carlos-rocha).

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema ocorre pelo fato dos atributos estarem privados e o json_encode não conseguir extrair os valores.

Vejo algumas soluções:

```
 json_encode(serialize(get_object_vars($x)));

 json_encode((array) $x);
```

Você poderia adicionar uma função no seu objeto que retorna dos dados:

```
public function toArray() { return (array) $this; }
//chamando assim:
json_encode($obj->toArray())
```

Comment: como eu disse, json_encode(serialize($x))); resolveu. Porém, tenho um campo de texto que aceita html. então, em um deles, foi colocado um href fechado adequadamente. Porém, abaixo dele, e em todo o resultado do json ficou com um link gigante. Será que há problema?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86386/discussion-between-edson-alves-and-carlos-rocha).